# Edit model including navigation properties MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, navigation

I have a Person Model:

```
Partial Public Class Person
Public Property Id As Long
<DisplayName("Fornavn")>
Public Property Firstname As String
<DisplayName("Efternavn")>
Public Property Lastname As String
Public Property chr_cpr As String
<DisplayName("Medarbejdernummer")>
Public Property EmployeeNumber As String


Public Overridable Property Accounts As ICollection(Of Account) = New HashSet(Of Account)

Public Overridable Property PaymentCards As ICollection(Of PaymentCard) = New HashSet(Of PaymentCard)

Public Overridable Property PaymentRoles As ICollection(Of PaymentRole) = New HashSet(Of PaymentRole)

Public Overridable Property AllPaymentRoles As ICollection(Of PaymentRole) = New HashSet(Of PaymentRole)

Public Overridable Property BillableDepartments As ICollection(Of Department) = New HashSet(Of Department)

Public Overridable Property AllDepartments As ICollection(Of Department) = New HashSet(Of Department)

Public Overridable Property AccessablePosDevices As ICollection(Of PosDevice) = New HashSet(Of PosDevice)

Public Overridable Property AllPosDevices As ICollection(Of PosDevice) = New HashSet(Of PosDevice)

End Class
```

And an account model:

```
Partial Public Class Account
Public Property Id As Long
Public Property PersonId As Long
Public Property Balance As Decimal
Public Property SchemaId As Long
Public Property HasAutoRefill As Boolean

Public Overridable Property Schema As AccountSchema
Public Overridable Property Person As Person

End Class
```

And a paymentCard model:

```
Partial Public Class PaymentCard
Public Property Id As Long
Public Property Serial As String
Public Property TypeId As Nullable(Of Long)
Public Property IsActive As Boolean
Public Property PersonId As Long

Public Overridable Property Type As CardType
Public Overridable Property Person As Person
End Class
```

I want to be able to edit Person, PaymentCard and Account properties from the Person/Edit view. I'm using EditorTemplates. This is my view:

```
@ModelType IDCompany.WEB.Person

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@<fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Firstname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Firstname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Firstname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Lastname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Lastname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Lastname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.chr_cpr)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.chr_cpr)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.chr_cpr)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeNumber)
    </div>
 </fieldset>


@<table class="cardTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Serienummer</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Aktiv</th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.PaymentCards)
</table>

@Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Accounts)


@<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>

End Using
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

Here is my Person/EditorTemplates/Account:

```
@ModelType IDCompany.WEB.Account

    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.PersonId)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.HasAutoRefill)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.SchemaId)
```

And my Person/EditorTemplates/PaymentCard:

```
@ModelType IDCompany.WEB.PaymentCard


        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.TypeId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.PersonId)

        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) Model.Serial)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) Model.Type.Name)
 <tr class="cardRow">
            <td>@Model.Id</td>
            <td>@Model.Serial</td>
            <td>@Model.Type.Name</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IsActive)</td>
 </tr>
```

And this is the edit function in my PersonController:

```
        <HttpPost()> _
    Function Edit(ByVal person As Person) As ActionResult
        Dim kontoSubMenu As New List(Of MenuPoint)
        Dim emptyList As New List(Of String)
        kontoSubMenu.Add(New MenuPoint("Kantine", emptyList, "Kontooplysninger", "Home", "All"))
        kontoSubMenu.Add(New MenuPoint("Personer", emptyList, "Personer", "Person", "All"))
        kontoSubMenu.Add(New MenuPoint("Test", emptyList, "LogUd", "Home", "All"))
        ViewBag.kontoSubMenu = kontoSubMenu
        If ModelState.IsValid Then

            Dim paymentcardList
            paymentcardList = person.PaymentCards.ToList()
            For Each pc In paymentcardList
                db.Entry(pc).State = EntityState.Modified

                db.SaveChanges()

            Next
            Dim accountList
            accountList = person.Accounts.ToList()
            For Each ac As Account In accountList
                db.Entry(ac).State = EntityState.Modified
                'Dim accountValue As Account = db.Accounts.Find(accountt.Id)

                db.SaveChanges()
            Next

            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If

        Return View(person)
    End Function
```

I'm new at MVC.
When I'm trying to edit som data in the view I get the error:
"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship." on "db.Entry(pc).State = EntityState.Modified"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your code:

1. Why are you calling `db.SaveChanges()` many times in your action? You should call it only once at the end. Save all or nothing.
2. When the modelbinder creates the parameter objects for your action, it knows nothing about EF. For example the `Person` property of the `PaymentCard` objects won't get set. This is probably the point EF is complaining about when you try to reattach the object to your datacontext by calling `db.Entry(pc).State = EntityState.Modified`. You should requery the objects by id from the database and map the desired / changed properties. Its even better to not pass the EF classes directly to the view but use plain ViewModel classes instead.
3. You use `EditorFor` for the property `Person.PaymentCards` which is of type `ICollection(Of PaymentCard)`. Your EditorTemplate has a modeltype of `PaymentCard`. That won't work. You could write another EditorTemplate for `ICollection(Of PaymentCard)` or just iterate in your view (sorry, in C#):

   ```
   @foreach(var acc in Model.Accounts) {
       @Html.EditorFor(m => acc)
   }
   ```